# UWP how to get shorcuts from folder

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10, win-universal-app

So I've been messing around to add an explorer functionality to an UWP app I'm working on for a school project and was able to get mostly everything I needed working.

One thing I wasn't able to figure out however, is how to get shortcut files as they don't seem to be considered a StorageFile.
You can see in the picture below that the shortcut is missing.
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFkxN.png]

Is there a way to do this using the UWP API or do I have to use a win32 FullTrustProcess?

This is how I'm getting the files:

```
            var folder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(Path);
            IReadOnlyList<IStorageItem> items = (await folder.GetItemsAsync()).OrderBy(_f => (_f is StorageFile)?0:-1).ToList().AsReadOnly();
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not supported to get a shortcut file as a `StorageFile` instance. You could try to use a `FileOpenPicker` to get your target shortcut file, and you will find the `StorageFile` instance you got is the target of the shortcut file instead of the shortcut file itself.

You may need to use a win32 API with **Desktop Bridge** to get shortcut files.

Comment: I figured as much. Thank you for the answer. Thankfully I already have an AppServiceConnection working with a win32 app